# Уточняющий оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Принципиальная схема решения, после выяснения всех требований, представляет из себя следующее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые не нужны. "Представляет из себя" - разговорный вариант. Правильно "представляет собой".